# $http and $ajax request returning status 0 randomly in Chrome

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, nginx, gunicorn

This does not happen all the time on the site but it happens once in a while.

The browser starts returning status 0 for XMLHTTPRequest requests in the page randomly.

This holds true for requests made through  jquery ajax function and the $http resource in angularJS

There is nothing in the network tab when this happens. The requests do not even go through to the network layer.

But the issue disappears after a refresh only to appear randomly.

I do not do a lot of testing on Firefox but I have never experienced it there

I am using relating paths only. The cross domain issue does not even arise.

I have tried looking at multiple questions on stackoverflow but nothing has helped me resolve it

I am using nginx as a reverse proxy to gunicorn server running a pyramid web application.

What intrigues me is that it works sometimes and sometimes does not. Any ideas?

If I do

```
$.ajax({url: '/json/1/sources', 
    success: function(d){console.log(d)},
    error: function(){
        console.log("error");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(arguments))
    }})
```

I get

```
error
{"0":{"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"},"1":"error","2":""}
```

as the output

**MORE INFO**

The moment I open Javascript console and click on `disable cache while dev tools is open`, the problem stops

Comment: Give and you will receive. Give us some code and you might have some answers :)

Comment: Added a snippet I ran from the console when I got this error

Comment: Looks like a server side issue, maybe due to proxy

Comment: But it works correctly sometimes

Comment: "But it works correctly sometimes" <- Definitely a server issue.

Comment: how do you deduce that? Give me some logic or ask me questions some more questions. There has to be some reason you are saying that unless you are going by intuition

Comment: also it works again on reload. Plus I should say it works correctly most of the time

Answer (score 1):

So here is what I had to do to get rid of this random error. It might sound unscientific but in case someone ever face this error, this might help.

In case I got that error, I just remove the `X-Requested-With` key from the header and retry the request.

```
if($http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With']){
                delete $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];

 }
```

And things start working. That's it.

I have never had use for this header. So I do not mind removing it.

Some spooky things do happen in Javascript sometimes, even through you might think you got everything covered.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... did you find something on nginx configuration or it was solved this way?